# why does '/' have the inode number 2?

Tags: linux, file, unix, linux-kernel, directory-structure

why does '/' have the inode number 2 ? whereas this is the first directory file of *nix Filesystem Hierarchy, which gets created at first, then logically Inode number of '/' should be 1, but it is not, why??

[Here the image will tell more about this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Umnii.png).

Comment: You have to provide more information.

Comment: Thank you @Jean-Baptiste Yunès, This link was also useful to me. http://140.120.7.21/LinuxKernel/LinuxKernel/node16.html